# Convert double dimension json array to C# class

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am getting JSON output in the below format. I want to read it in C#. I tried to convert the JSON to C# class. but, still not able to read this output. Can anyone help here? the main problem I am facing here is with "rows". it seems like double dimension array and I don't know, how to create its C# class. Please provide me solution with some examples. Thanks.

```
{
"database_id": 9,
"row_count": 2,
"data": {
    "rows": [
        [
            "242376_dpi65990",
            "ppo",
            "2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            8,
            8
        ],
        [
            "700328_dpi66355",
            "ppo",
            "2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            9,
            6
        ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get chance to look into my answer? was it helpful?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to get model for your json,

1. Use online tool https://json2csharp.com/ to convert json to C# class model
2. You can use visual studio inbuild feature called "Paste JSON as a Classes".

   *EDIT -> Paste Spacial -> Paste JSON as a Classes*

[image]

I used first approach to get is model stucture for your json string,

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 

public class Data    {
    public List<List<object>> rows { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public int database_id { get; set; } 
    public int row_count { get; set; } 
    public Data data { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using JObject.
the main problem was with content inside the array.

```
[
        "242376_dpi65990",
        "ppo",
        "2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        8,
        8
    ]
```

Since, there was no Key name in this, I was not able to get its class.
I used JObject.

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(resultString);
rowCount = int.Parse(rss["row_count"].ToString());
var value1 = rss["data"]["rows"][0][0].ToString();
var value2 = rss["data"]["rows"][0][1].ToString();
var value3 = rss["data"]["rows"][0][2].ToString();
var value4 = rss["data"]["rows"][0][3].ToString();
```